# Direct link to post when multiple categories are selected

Tags: permalinks, breadcrumb

I have an custom Permalinks format: `/%category%/%postname%`

It works fine as each posts gets link base on category, like `category1/sub-category1/post-title`.

The problem is, when I assign the post to several categories, I cannot control which "path" will be chosen for link under direct link:
[image]

On given example, the post has been added to category `specjalne/produkty` as well as `kosmetyki/do-twarzy`. I would like the direct link to point for `kosmetyki/do-twarzy/...` instead of `specjalne/produkty/...`

Also, `get_permalink()` returns the same link as direct link field (and I want it to change to `kosmetyki/do-twarzy/...`).

The best solution would be to never create path based on `specjalne/produkty` if there is any other option available - because it should be the lowest priority path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the [Yoast SEO](https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/) plugin to enable this:

[image]